# Transferring old callsign to a club?

Tags: united-states, legal, callsign

A new vanity callsign will be granted to me (currently in pending level 2 stage).

Can I transfer my current soon to be cancelled callsign (vanity) to a club which I am trustee without waiting the two years for the club to apply for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Per the [FCC vanity callsign FAQs](https://www.fcc.gov/wireless/bureau-divisions/mobility-division/amateur-radio-service/amateur-vanity-request-types-3):

> Q: Can I request that the call sign I vacated be assigned to my new club station under the former holder provision?
>
> A: No. Your club station was not the holder of the call sign you vacated. After two years, your club station license trustee might apply for it under the request-by-list provision.